# Rate of convergence of ergodic averages related to irrational rotation

Tags: nt.number-theory, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, ergodic-theory, asymptotics, limits-and-convergence

Let $\alpha$ be an irrational number, consider the basic dynamical system $T^{n}(0) = \{n \alpha\}$ where $\{.\}$ denotes the fractional part.
Let $a < b$ be two numbers in $[0, 1]$. Then by Birkhoff's ergodic theorem and a little unique ergodicity argument we can prove that
$$\operatorname{lim}_{N\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i = 0}^{N-1} \chi(T^{i}(0)) = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i = 0} ^{N-1} \chi(\{i \alpha\}) = \int_{[0,1]} \chi=b-a $$
where $\chi$ is the characteristic function of the interval $[a, b]$.
My question is that what can be said about the rate of this convergence. More specifically how large can be the discrepancy term $|\sum_{i=0}^{N-1} \chi(\{i \alpha\}) - N(b - a)|$ as a function of $N$?

Comment: This is very tricky.  Check the book   *Irregularities of Distribution* by  Beck and  Chen and also  W.M Schmidt's articles with the same name.

Answer (score 7):

For a detailed account of this well-studied problem see, for example, Chapter 2 of *Uniform Distribution of Sequences* by  L. Kuipers and  H. Niederreiter.